after migrating to Arm CPU, zsh and oh-my-zsh plugins give `compint` warnings
I recently migrated from an Intel-based Macbook to an Arm-based Macbook. As part of the migration, I copied over files including my Homebrew installation.
It turns out this has caused some issues and I successfully deleted everything in /usr/local/share and switch to a new Homebrew in /opt/local/share with Arm-based packages.
But my zsh keep referencing some stuff in the old Homebrew. Half the time I start a new terminal session, I get errors like the following:
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_argo
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_aws
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_azcopy
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_bat
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_csvtk
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_delta
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_fd
compinit:shift:529: shift count must be <= $#
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_flyctl
compinit:shift:529: shift count must be <= $#
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_fnm
compinit:shift:529: shift count must be <= $#
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_gh
compinit:shift:529: shift count must be <= $#
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_git
compinit:shift:529: shift count must be <= $#
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_helm
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_highlight
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_j
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_jc
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_jo
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_kubectl
compinit:shift:529: shift count must be <= $#
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_parallel
compinit:shift:529: shift count must be <= $#
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_pdfgrep
compinit:shift:529: shift count must be <= $#
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_pipenv
compinit:shift:529: shift count must be <= $#
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_rclone
compinit:shift:529: shift count must be <= $#
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_rg
compinit:shift:529: shift count must be <= $#
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_tldr
compinit:shift:529: shift count must be <= $#
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_yq
compinit:shift:529: shift count must be <= $#
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_yt-dlp
compinit:shift:529: shift count must be <= $#
upgrcompinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_argo
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_aws
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_azcopy
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_bat
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_csvtk
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_delta
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_fd
compinit:shift:529: shift count must be <= $#
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_flyctl
compinit:shift:529: shift count must be <= $#
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_fnm
compinit:shift:529: shift count must be <= $#
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_gh
compinit:shift:529: shift count must be <= $#
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_git
compinit:shift:529: shift count must be <= $#
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_helm
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_highlight
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_j
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_jc
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_jo
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_kubectl
compinit:shift:529: shift count must be <= $#
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_parallel
compinit:shift:529: shift count must be <= $#
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_pdfgrep
compinit:shift:529: shift count must be <= $#
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_pipenv
compinit:shift:529: shift count must be <= $#
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_rclone
compinit:shift:529: shift count must be <= $#
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_rg
compinit:shift:529: shift count must be <= $#
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_tldr
compinit:shift:529: shift count must be <= $#
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_yq
compinit:shift:529: shift count must be <= $#
compinit:527: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_yt-dlp
compinit:shift:529: shift count must be <= $#

I'm using both zsh and oh-my-zsh plugins. I've tried deleted and fully reinstalling both. But I can't get these errors to go away.
Any pointers others can offer? Thanks.

You may need to check its startup files for any references to /usr/local/share and change them to /opt/homebrew/share.
The simple way would be to run
rm -rf /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
ln -s /opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions


That seems to have solved the problem. Thanks!
I'm still not sure what/where are the references to /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions are still living, but that's less of a concern now.
